# Prove $\frac{x-1}{x}$ has exactly two real solutions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How do I prove $\frac{x-1}{x}=0$ has two real solutions?

I know it has one solution at $x=1$, but the question said "find the 2 real solutions", so I was confused if I was overlooking something. Maybe it's an error in the question.

Does anybody have any ideas to this problem?

Comment: Usually one talk about solutions when there is an equation (or inequation) involve, but in your question there was only one function. Are you sure you should not include some $=$, or some inequality?

Comment: Shouldn't this be equal to something if it is to have "solutions?" I don't see an equation. Unless if you're asking if $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{x}$ has exactly two real roots.

Comment: This question is not well posed just yet. To what is it supposed to be equal?

Comment: If roots are meant, there is only one. At the root of the denominator , the function has a pole. Maybe, the OP means "asymptotics". In this case, we actually have two , namely $x=0$ and $y=1$

Comment: Ah yes I meant (x-1)/x = 0 , I know it has one solution but the question said find the 2 real solutions so I was confused if I was overlooking something. Maybe it's an error in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Well, assuming you want to find the roots of $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$:
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}
$$
The roots are given when $f(x)=0$, so
$$
1=\frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow x=1
$$

You could even plot $f(x)$ to see it:[image]

Comment: (+1) for showing the graph of the function. Whatever is meant : This answer should be helpful.